# comparing string repetitively returns wrong value

Tags: c, strcmp, strlen

In the below program I am trying to copy string data "eth0" into the array of structure containing string data and a count defined as below.
strcmp returns true for the first index but for other two it returns false even after copying same string.

```c
    typedef struct interface_data {
    char eth[4];
    int  cnt;
    } interface;

  

    int main()
    {
    static interface obj[3];
    int i = 0;
    int len;
    char buffer[4] = "eth1";
    for(i = 0 ; i < 3; i++){
        if(strcmp(obj[i].eth,"") == 0)
            printf("yes\n");
        strcpy(obj[i].eth,buffer);
        len = strlen(obj[i].eth);
        printf("%d len of string\n",len);
        obj[i].eth[len] = '\0';
        obj[i].cnt = i;
        len = strcmp(obj[i].eth,"eth1");
        if(len == 0)
            printf("true\n"); //returns true only for the first index
        else
            printf("\n%d wrong data\n",len); //remainig two index fails
    
        char *p = obj[i].eth;
        while(*p != '\0') {
            printf("%c\t",*p);
            p++;
        }
        printf("\ndata %s and cnt %d\n",obj[i].eth,obj[i].cnt);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "eth0" needs 5 chars, net 4, because of the terminating `'\0'`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `strcpy(obj[i].eth,buffer);` with `char buffer[4] = "eth1";` is bad. `buffer` doesn't have terminating null-character, which is required in C strings, so using that as the input of `strcpy()` is illegal.

You can remove the explicit number of elements like `char buffer[] = "eth1";` to have the compiler decide enough number of elements to store the string including the terminating null-character.

Also the member `char eth[4];` of the structure `interface` is too short to accept `"eth1` being copied. You have to allocate enough elements to store the string including the terminating null-character.

Another note is that `obj[i].eth[len] = '\0';` after `len = strlen(obj[i].eth);` is redundant because `obj[i].eth[len]` must already be `'\0'` according to the definition of strings in C.

Comment: thank you. I missed out the simple stuff sorry for that